# How to create a shared or static library from redis source code?

Tags: java, c, linux, redis, java-native-interface

I am trying to invoke redis functions from Java using JNI. Due to some performance reasons, I can't use redis java client. I have to interact directly with redis server side source code.
But even the first step seems difficult for me. In JNI, it must load a native library while redis doesn't have such library like "libredis.so" or "libredis.a".

I tried to create a static library using ar command. But it can't work properly, because it has some other dependency directories.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get `hiredis` from [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/tree/unstable/deps/hiredis), if that's what you mean. Build it as a shared object, pay attention to the required memory architecture.

> "interact directly with redis server side source code"

This line confuses me a bit, but I think I'm steering you in the right direction.